# PHP Arrays : How to Find the Lowest/Highest Value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array like this :

```
$array1 = array(1,1,2,3,3,4,5); //remember that i have two '1' value in this array
$array2 = array($url1, $url2, $url3, $url4, $url5, $url6);
```

I wish to find the lowest/highest value in $array1 then link to $url1/$url5 like this :

```
<a href="$url1">1</a> or <a href="$url6">5</a>
```

How I can make this happen using PHP? Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php , http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php.  By the way, that's not an associative array.

Comment: Check out the PHP functions "min()", "max()" and "mt_rand()".

Or be a bit more precise about what you need, do you want to find the lowest urls and then the lowest in alphanumerical order or just a random url associated with the lowest number?

Comment: I'm sorry Michael for the wrong question title, thanks for correction :)

Comment: You have two 1's in the first array. Should it choose `$url1` or `$url2` in the second array?

Comment: I assume you are wanting to match the elements in the first array to those in the second but your first array has 7 elements and the second only has 6?

Comment: Thanks @Juhana, I want to pick the first value found for that 1 value and hyperlink to $url1, is it possible?

Comment: I'm sorry John, my bad :) Yes i want to match the elements in first array to the second

Comment: Is the array already sorted like in your example?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) & [min()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) function

> max — Find highest value
>   min — Find lowest value

Example code:

```
$max = max($array);
$min = min($array);
```

Comment: Thanks Bono. Yes, I've implemented those min and max, but how can I make a hyperlink to value in array2 ?

Comment: Is $url1 supposed to be a key or a value?

Comment: both array doesn't contain key, only value :(

Comment: I know, but do you want to call the value of your array like so: $array['url1']; Which then outputs "1"?

Comment: Sorry Bono :) I just confuse with this array function, do you have any suggestion to output the lowest value using min(array) that contain  hyperlink to $url1 ?

Comment: The way you put your sentence makes me not get what you want to do unfortunatly. Could you please try and elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This is what I try to achieve. I have 3 variable that contain price of product from 3 different store. And I have 3 variable that contain URL to each store. How do I put these value into array so I can get the lowest/highest price from the first 3 variable ( price range) and link to it store.

Answer (score 2):

If the array is already sorted, use `$array2[0]` and `$array2[count($array2)-1]`.

If it's not already sorted, you can use this to sort the arrays.

```
array_multisort($array1, SORT_NUMERIC, $array2);
$lowest = $array2[0];
$highest = $array2[count($array2)-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you need this 2 functions: [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php), [min](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php)

Comment: I did, but how about hyperlink as stated above? :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$maxValueKeys = array_keys($array1, max($array1)); // Your min value indexes
$minValueKeys = array_keys($array1, min($array1)); // Your max value indexes
```

But it isn't an associative array